# Efficient way to loop through python dict?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have a `python` `dict` which has the following format:

```
for (itemA, itemB) in items.keys():
    Do_something_with(itemA, itemB)
```

`itemA` has many `itemB`'s associated with it, but it is non-deterministic. For example, one instance of `itemA` may have 10 `itemB`'s, but another instance of `itemA` may only have 1.

I would like to loop through the array as something like:

```
thing = 0
for (itemA, ~) in items.keys()[0]:
    for itemB in all_items_associated_with(itemA):
        thing += function_on(itemA, itemB)
```

I can come up with some ways to do this that are horribly expensive computationally, but I feel like there is a more pythonic and/or efficient way to do this. Here is a horribly expensive method

```
thing = 0
itemAs = find_all_itemAs(items)
for itemA in itemAs:
    for (itemAtmp, itemB) in items.keys():
        if( itemAtmp == itemA ):
            thing += function_on(itemA, itemB)
```

but I know that's pretty horrible.

Comment: So the keys are tuples?

Comment: What's wrong with `for (itemA, itemB) in items.keys()`? (Besides the unnecessary parentheses and the `keys` call.)

Comment: please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, keys are tuples and the values are also tuples. The only thing wrong with `for (itemA, itemB) in items.keys()` is that I can't be sure that all items associated with `itemA` will be looped over at the same time. I want to calculate statistics on all `itemB`'s associated with `itemA`, but I also need to be able to reference the collected tuple `(itemA, itemB)` efficiently which is why I am using it as a key.

Comment: This is a question that should be posted on code review as it is a cooperative review type question.

Comment: Don't use `.keys()` just to iterate a dict. On Python2, that stops and makes a list just for the purpose of iterating. `for (itemA, itemB) in items:` instead will work fine

Comment: It feels like items should be a dict of dict. Is there a reason for keeping the keys coupled into a tuple?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
for itemA in dict:
    for itemB in dict[itemA]:
        thing += finction_on(itemA, itemB)
```

This will loop through all of the keys of the dictionary and all of the items at those keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` and `itertools.groupby` to efficiently group together the related items.

```
keys = sorted(items.keys())
for itemA, it in itertools.groupby(keys, lambda x: x[0]):
    for _, itemB in it:
        thing += function_on(itemA, itemB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are possible alternatives:

- Use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the related keys:

  ```
  for itm_a, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(dict), lambda itm_a, itm_b: itm_a):
      # now we can process everything that has the same first item
      my_thing = sum([function_on(itm_a, itm_b) for _, itm_b in group], 0)
  ```
- a similar approach, without using [itertools.group_by](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), is to discover the groups yourself

  ```
  groups = {}
  for itm_a, itm_b in dict:
      groups.setdefault(itm_a, []).append(itm_b)

  # now we can process all of the related keys together
  for itm_a, all_itm_b in groups.items():
      # do something
      my_thing = sum([function_on(itm_a, itm_b) for itm_b in all_itm_b], 0)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just using the wrong data structure, you really want a dict of dicts so you can do something like this:

```
for itemA in dictOfDicts:
    thing = 0
    for itemB in dictOfDicts[itemA]:
        value = dictOfDicts[itemA][itemB]
        thing += fun(itemA, itemB, value)
    save(thing)
```

You can easily get a dict of dicts from your current data structure by doing something like this:

```
dictOfDicts = {}
for (itemA, itemB) in items:
    if itemA not in dictOfDicts:
        dictOfDicts[itemA] = {}
    dictOfDicts[itemA][itemB] = items[itemA, itemB]
```